# drive access got extremely slow

Tags: hard-disk, performance

The HDD of my laptop got extremely slow all of the sudden (after a reboot).

`hdparm` tells me that cached and buffered reads are both in the range of hundreds of kB/sec - that's slower than my ethernet.

The other disk, which is an SSD, is still reasonably fast (tens to hundreds of MB/sec).

I cannot recall making any change to the system configuration whatsoever. The machine is about 4 years old now and has seen some heavy use, so hardware failure would not be out of the ordinary - still, I'd love to understand what exactly happened to my disk to make it so unbearably slow.

What are good ways to diagnose the issue and decide whether this is anything that can be fixed software-side, or whether this HDD's days are just over?

- `iotop` shows a few processes clogging the writing every now and then (most notably chrome), but this is in the hundreds of kb - nothing that a healthy disk should not be able to handle, I hope
- the HD is 2 TB and is only 55% full
- my machine has 32 GB of memory, and basically none of it is in active use while the problem is showing up. no swapping is happening.
- the disk is ext4 formatted
- `gnome-disks` shows nothing out of the ordinary and claims "Disk is OK"

Any help is greatly appreciated!

## EDIT

smartctl output:

```
smartctl -a

smartctl 7.2 2020-12-30 r5155 [x86_64-linux-5.11.9-arch1-1] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-20, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Seagate Barracuda 2.5 5400
Device Model:     ST2000LM015-2E8174
Serial Number:    WDZ42GC1
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000c50 0a924e67a
Firmware Version: SDM1
User Capacity:    2,000,398,934,016 bytes [2.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    5400 rpm
Form Factor:      2.5 inches
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ACS-3 T13/2161-D revision 3b
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.1, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Thu Sep 16 15:34:18 2021 CEST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (    0) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x71) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    No Auto Offline data collection support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    No Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   1) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 326) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x3035) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 10
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000f   083   064   006    Pre-fail  Always       -       178015037
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0003   099   099   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   094   094   020    Old_age   Always       -       6386
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   036    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000f   079   060   045    Pre-fail  Always       -       21859995677
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   090   090   000    Old_age   Always       -       9557 (203 232 0)
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   097    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   094   094   020    Old_age   Always       -       6312
184 End-to-End_Error        0x0032   100   100   099    Old_age   Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
188 Command_Timeout         0x0032   100   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       2
189 High_Fly_Writes         0x003a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0022   067   050   040    Old_age   Always       -       33 (Min/Max 24/33)
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       81
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       65
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   070   070   000    Old_age   Always       -       61546
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   033   050   000    Old_age   Always       -       33 (0 10 0 0 0)
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0010   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x003e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
240 Head_Flying_Hours       0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       9437 (13 80 0)
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       15466926078
242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       8392824054
254 Free_Fall_Sensor        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      9553         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

dmesg output:

```
sudo dmesg -t --level=alert,crit,err,warn
MDS CPU bug present and SMT on, data leak possible. See https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/hw-vuln/mds.html for more details.
 #3
ata3.00: supports DRM functions and may not be fully accessible
ata3.00: supports DRM functions and may not be fully accessible
vboxdrv: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
VBoxNetAdp: Successfully started.
VBoxNetFlt: Successfully started.
r8169 0000:03:00.1: can't disable ASPM; OS doesn't have ASPM control
platform regulatory.0: Direct firmware load for regulatory.db failed with error -2
kauditd_printk_skb: 33 callbacks suppressed
kauditd_printk_skb: 10 callbacks suppressed
kauditd_printk_skb: 146 callbacks suppressed
```

`hdparm -I output`

```
/dev/sda:

ATA device, with non-removable media
    Model Number:       ST2000LM015-2E8174                      
    Serial Number:      WDZ42GC1
    Firmware Revision:  SDM1    
    Transport:          Serial, ATA8-AST, SATA 1.0a, SATA II Extensions, SATA Rev 2.5, SATA Rev 2.6, SATA Rev 3.0
Standards:
    Used: unknown (minor revision code 0x001f) 
    Supported: 10 9 8 7 6 5 
    Likely used: 10
Configuration:
    Logical     max current
    cylinders   16383   16383
    heads       16  16
    sectors/track   63  63
    --
    CHS current addressable sectors:    16514064
    LBA    user addressable sectors:   268435455
    LBA48  user addressable sectors:  3907029168
    Logical  Sector size:                   512 bytes
    Physical Sector size:                  4096 bytes
    Logical Sector-0 offset:                  0 bytes
    device size with M = 1024*1024:     1907729 MBytes
    device size with M = 1000*1000:     2000398 MBytes (2000 GB)
    cache/buffer size  = unknown
    Form Factor: 2.5 inch
    Nominal Media Rotation Rate: 5400
Capabilities:
    LBA, IORDY(can be disabled)
    Queue depth: 32
    Standby timer values: spec'd by Standard, no device specific minimum
    R/W multiple sector transfer: Max = 16  Current = 16
    Advanced power management level: 128
    Recommended acoustic management value: 208, current value: 208
    DMA: mdma0 mdma1 mdma2 udma0 udma1 udma2 udma3 udma4 udma5 *udma6 
         Cycle time: min=120ns recommended=120ns
    PIO: pio0 pio1 pio2 pio3 pio4 
         Cycle time: no flow control=120ns  IORDY flow control=120ns
Commands/features:
    Enabled Supported:
       *    SMART feature set
            Security Mode feature set
       *    Power Management feature set
       *    Write cache
       *    Look-ahead
       *    Host Protected Area feature set
       *    WRITE_BUFFER command
       *    READ_BUFFER command
       *    NOP cmd
       *    DOWNLOAD_MICROCODE
       *    Advanced Power Management feature set
            Power-Up In Standby feature set
       *    SET_FEATURES required to spinup after power up
            SET_MAX security extension
       *    48-bit Address feature set
       *    Device Configuration Overlay feature set
       *    Mandatory FLUSH_CACHE
       *    FLUSH_CACHE_EXT
       *    SMART error logging
       *    SMART self-test
       *    General Purpose Logging feature set
       *    WRITE_{DMA|MULTIPLE}_FUA_EXT
       *    64-bit World wide name
       *    IDLE_IMMEDIATE with UNLOAD
            Write-Read-Verify feature set
       *    WRITE_UNCORRECTABLE_EXT command
       *    {READ,WRITE}_DMA_EXT_GPL commands
       *    Segmented DOWNLOAD_MICROCODE
       *    Gen1 signaling speed (1.5Gb/s)
       *    Gen2 signaling speed (3.0Gb/s)
       *    Gen3 signaling speed (6.0Gb/s)
       *    Native Command Queueing (NCQ)
       *    Host-initiated interface power management
       *    Phy event counters
       *    Idle-Unload when NCQ is active
       *    READ_LOG_DMA_EXT equivalent to READ_LOG_EXT
       *    DMA Setup Auto-Activate optimization
       *    Device-initiated interface power management
            Asynchronous notification (eg. media change)
       *    Software settings preservation
       *    SMART Command Transport (SCT) feature set
       *    SCT Write Same (AC2)
       *    SCT Features Control (AC4)
       *    SCT Data Tables (AC5)
            unknown 206[12] (vendor specific)
            unknown 206[13] (vendor specific)
       *    DOWNLOAD MICROCODE DMA command
Security: 
    Master password revision code = 65534
        supported
    not enabled
    not locked
    not frozen
    not expired: security count
        supported: enhanced erase
    326min for SECURITY ERASE UNIT. 326min for ENHANCED SECURITY ERASE UNIT.
Logical Unit WWN Device Identifier: 5000c500a924e67a
    NAA     : 5
    IEEE OUI    : 000c50
    Unique ID   : 0a924e67a
Checksum: correct
```

Comment: Please post `smartctl -a` output https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Analyzing_a_Faulty_Hard_Disk_using_Smartctl and `dmesg -t --level=alert,crit,err,warn`

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov thanks, missing info added

Comment: Nothing in your logs indicates any issues. Sorry, I've got no clue.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov thanks a lot for your time already, maybe someone else comes along with an idea!

Comment: Oh, another idea, please post `hdparm -I` output as well.

Comment: done, hope this helps!

Comment: `hdparm` says the disk is running in ***udma6** mode, i.e. everything should be perfect. I've no idea what could be wrong. Try powering it off, disconnecting the battery for 10 minutes and then plug it in and turn it on.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov I am having similar issues lately. Were you able to figure out what was the culprit?

Comment: Nope, that's not my HW.